# I am trying to validate schema having integer array in karate

Tags: arrays, validation, integer, schema, karate

I am trying to validate integer array schema but getting Error assertion failed:actual :{applications=[2,5,7], assigned_doctors=[100014,90], additional_roles=[10,19]
    expected: {applications=##[], assigned_doctors=#[], additional_roles=#[]}

```
I am not able to find correct syntax to validate array of integer.

Response:

 "userdetail": {
    "applications": [
      2,
      5,
      7
    ],
    "assigned_doctors": [
      100014,
      90
    ],
    "additional_roles": [
      10,
      19
    ],

Structure:  
"""
    {
     userdetail:{
     applications: ##[], 
     assigned_doctors: #[],
     additional_roles: #[]
     },

  When def getUserByIdUrl = 'http:xyz//UserRegistration/getUserById/105'
    And header Content-Type = 'application/json; charset=utf-8
    And header auth_token = token     
    And url getUserByIdUrl
    And method GET
    Then status 200
    And def getUserByIdData = response
    And print getUserByIdData  
"""
    {
     userdetail:{
     applications: ##[], 
     assigned_doctors: #[],
     additional_roles: #[]
     },

actual: {applications=[2,5,7], assigned_doctors=[100014,90], additional_roles=[10,19]

expected: 

expected: {applications=##[], assigned_doctors=#[], additional_roles=#[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, next time paste your response JSON properly so that it is well-formed. You can paste the below into a new `Scenario` and see it work. And read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#schema-validation

```
* def response =
"""
{
  "userdetail": {
    "applications": [
      2,
      5,
      7
    ],
    "assigned_doctors": [
      100014,
      90
    ],
    "additional_roles": [
      10,
      19
    ]
  }
}
"""
* match response == 
"""
{ 
  userdetail: {
    applications: '#[] #number',
    assigned_doctors: '#[] #number',
    additional_roles: '#[] #number'
  }
}
"""
```